# How to get the values of the first and last entry of a week/month/year?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

4Suppose I have a dataframe that looks like this

```
df:

date               open      close
2020-04-26           45         10
2020-04-28           15        20
2020-05-04           35        30
2020-05-05           35        40
```

and for example, I want to get the first and last entry of the week

```
Week 1 :  
First Entry = 45
Last Entry = 20

Week 2 :  
First Entry = 35
Last Entry = 40
```

Thank you very much to those who will help

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, we can use `groupby` and use `dt` accessor `week`

```
weeks = df.sort_values('date').groupby(df['date'].dt.week).agg(first_entry=('open','first'),
                                 last_entry=('close','last'))


print(weeks)

      first_entry  last_entry
date                         
17             45          10
18             15          20
19             35          40
```

Comment: How about if the entries are  random?

Comment: What I mean is it does not matter whether it is a minimum/maximum value? For example, on 2020-04-26, the open and close value are both  equal to 10 then code above will not work

Comment: Im actually not concerned if the value is minimum or maximum. I just want to know if the value of the first entry decrease/increase at the end of the week/month/year. I edited ```df``` please take a look at it.

Comment: @user324313 we can use `first` & `last` sorry I misread your question - see edit.